# module ad620 setup

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to amplify a 200 mV DC signal to single-digit DC volts.  I purchased this module.  I am struggling to just zero this. [image]

I have my 200mV applied across -s and +s.  Power to the unit is coming from a 6v 100 mA DC power adapter and is placed across Vin and GND on the left.  I am measuring the output DC across Vout and GND on the right.

These are the hookups as recommended by the manufacturer.
[image]

My 100 mV signal is in place of the sensor. I tried with and without that GND -s jumper. The zero adjustment is the pot closest to the edge of the circuit board.
Are my hookups correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct. The Zero adjust is for 0mV in, if you are applying 100mV you probably won't be able to make the output 0 (gain dependent).

Try shorting the input +S to -S with -S connected to GND, turn the gain to minimum and adjust the zero pot to get 0 out.

The zero adjust circuit in this 'design' is not very good especially if the output is negative and supplying any current.